# postfix: accepting all email addresses for a domain except for a few

Tags: postfix

In sendmail, I can have a catchall address and reject email going to certain addresses in my aliases or virtusertable files:

```
adm@example.com                        error:5.1.1:550 User unknown
apache@example.com                     michael
root@example.com                       michael
daemon@example.com                     error:5.1.1:550 User unknown
dbus@example.com                       error:5.1.1:550 User unknown
ftp@example.com                        error:5.1.1:550 User unknown
@example.com                           catchall
```

But the above doesn't work in the postfix maps - it tries to deliver to the error: address.

What's the right way to accomplish this in postfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `check_recipient_access` directive (main.cf).

Add a file that lists the email addresses (followed by `reject`) and point the above directive to that file.

e.g.  `check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/deny`

/etc/postfix/deny:

```
denied_user@domain.tld reject
```

Remember to reload your configuration files - and perhaps restart postfix.

For more information, see: http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html and http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html